# Unity: Получить ошибки из консоли в типе string

Tags: unity3d, консоль

У меня в коде работает try-catch. Иногда зависимо от действии пользователя я могу получить ошибку то есть код идёт по стороне catch. Вот тогда мне надо получить всю ошибку из консоли в типе string и показать пользователю, чтобы он знал что у него там не правильно.

---

*В таком случае как я могу получить ошибки из консоли в типе string?*

Comment: если я вас правильно понял то вам нужно использовать yourException.Message

Comment: @Andrey а как это пишется. Я не нашёл такого метода либо переменную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try
{

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.LogError(ex.Message);
}
```

Просто пустой блок.  Ловите ошибку и выводите её сообщение. Так можно делать с любыми ошибками типа `NullReferenceException`,`IndexOutOfRangeException` и тд